# How do i make an image move in Python Mode for Processing?

Tags: python, processing, pyprocessing

**The movement part is all the way at the bottom**
How do I make an image move in Python Mode for Processing?
I tried everything and there are no tutorials on PyProcessing. Please Help
another way i tried is:
if keyPressed(39): (39 is right arrow key is ASCII)
(and then what ever)

```
def setup():
    global back, canvash, canvasw, cornerpointx, cornerpointy
    global invader, invaderx, invadery, invaderw, invaderh
    global ship, shipx, shipy, shipw, shiph
    global beam, beamw, beamh

    shipy = 0
    shipx = 0
    canvasw = 800
    canvash = 800
    shipw = 100
    shiph = 100
    shipx = 0
    shipy = 0
    beamw = 50
    beamh = 900
    invaderw = 50
    invaderh = 50
    size( canvasw,canvash )
    back = loadImage( "back.png" )
    ship = loadImage( "ship.png" )
    invader = loadImage( "alien.png" )

def draw():
    global back, canvash, canvasw, cornerpointx, cornerpointy
    global invader, invaderx, invadery, invaderw, invaderh
    global ship, shipx, shipy, shipw, shiph
    global beam, beamw, beamh

    background = image(back, 0, 0, canvasw, canvash)
    image(ship, shipx, shipy, shipw, shiph)
    image(invader, 100, 350, invaderw, invaderh)

def keyPressed():
    global back, canvash, canvasw, cornerpointx, cornerpointy
    global invader, invaderx, invadery, invaderw, invaderh
    global ship, shipx, shipy, shipw, shiph
    global beam, beamw, beamh

    if key == CODED:
        if keyPressed == LEFT:
            shipx = shipx + 10
```

Comment: Can you add a print statement to help figure out what's going on? Which of those if statements does it enter? What is the value of `shipx` when you draw the image?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the arrow keys you must check keyCode, not keyPressed, so try this:

```
if keyCode == LEFT:
    shipx = shipx + 10
```

Also, I don't know if you'll need to do these steps but for my testing, `if key == CODED` wasn't necessary and I had to move the variable declarations in `setup()` to the top of the program (for the images, set them to None at first then call `loadImage()` in `setup()`)